# How to approach CNN/image problem where pixel value is more than 255?

Tags: image, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, resnet

So I have a csv table where I have some values which are more than 255, so I basically make it into a image and pass it into resnet etc. Is there a particular approach I have to follow?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the input range? you'll anyway use normalization so the range must be known/

Answer (score 0):

What kind of image is it? Grayscale? RGB?

Keep in mind that not every image format is `8 bit` if you have a specific image format (e.g. 8 bit => `uint8`) you mostly normalize anyway by dividing by the maximum of the encoding. (In this case : `8 bit -> 2^8 = 256 - 1 = 255`

Even if you do not know the encoding, you can normalize by dividing your data by the maximum value occuring.

A possible implementation of that could look like this:

```
import numpy as np

def normalizeImage(image_data_array):  # Normalize images to 0 - 1
    return np.divide(image_data_array, np.amax(image_data_array))
```